# How may I have Ubuntu read an ASCII file out loud to me?

Tags: ubuntu, text-to-speech

Is there an easy way to have Ubuntu Linux to read a text file to me?

For example, let's say I have a file, `/tmp/test_type`; and in that file I have, `Hello, world`.  What is the easiest way to have Ubuntu  read that file -- or *any* file to me -- when my sight is failing?

Comment: A related question over on the AskUbuntu site about exactly this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/501910/how-to-text-to-speech-output-using-command-line

Comment: FWIW, and i hate to turn this into a chat-- I've bbeen running 18.04.  It seems a bit harder than 16.04.  That's neither here nor there.  I have orca on my laptop a meter away where it is easier to read and type.  Could someonee show me the How-to of using the 18.04 utility and my test file in /tmp?  Over in my lstop, I hsve what i want working, but only if i use /tmp/test0 in HTML.  Got to be an easier way.)

Comment: Withe the above examples, I found that "% cat /tmp/test | festival --tts"  MAY do it. I will   need to do further tests.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech) has a pretty good article going over several options.  Ubuntu has a [built-in screen reader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility) called Orca which you can use if you're using a graphical interface.

`espeak` may be pre-installed or, failing that, you can install it with `sudo apt install espeak`, after which you can use `espeak -f /tmp/test_type`.